# Implementing Progress Bar While Uploading the Image

Tags: objective-c, progress-bar, image-uploading

I am uploading the image and some string to server , it  is working fine ,now i am want to implement the Progress bar,if i am sending 5 images means ,i want to show the progress bar and i want to show the count of images sended successfully ,like 2 /5 ,Please anyone help me to do this. 
The follwoing method is for uploading image ,dictionary , and string

```
-(void)uploadImage
 {
NSString *userCategory = self.UserCategory;
NSDictionary *dict = [self.arrayWithImages objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex];
NSString *notes = [dict objectForKey:@"string"];
UIImage *sample = [dict objectForKey:@"image"];
NSData *sampleData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sample, 1.0);
NSMutableDictionary *FinalDict = [self.dictMetaData mutableCopy];
[FinalDict setObject:userCategory forKey:@"user_category"];
if (notes.length > 0) {
[FinalDict setObject:notes forKey:@"note"];
}
for (int i = 0; i<self.arrayWithImages.count; i++) {
[ServerUtility uploadImageWithAllDetails:FinalDict noteResource:sampleData andCompletion:^(NSError *error,id data)
{
if (!error) {
NSString *strResType = [data objectForKey:@"res_type"];
                       if ([strResType.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"success"]) {

                           NSLog(@"Upload Successfully");
                           self.currentIndex++;
                           }

                       else if ([strResType.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"error"])

                       {
                           NSString *strMsg = [data objectForKey:@"msg"];

                           [self.view makeToast:strMsg duration:1.0 position:CSToastPositionCenter];
                       }



                   }


                   else{

                        [self.view makeToast:error.localizedDescription duration:1.0 position:CSToastPositionCenter];

                   }



              }];




}
```

Comment: I think, after self.curentIndex++;
You change thread to main thread and change your progressBar value

Comment: Thanks Sambit , i have updated the progress bar label , but not progress bar please help me to do this